# Do any of these details contradict the idea that theory that this file is encrypted with Blowfish?

Tags: file-format, decryption, cryptanalysis

I have a file which has been encrypted with some unknown algorithm. Doing research on the file format, I stumbled across a website that claimed (without explaining why) that these files were encrypted with 32bit Blowfish. This website also speculates that the magic smoke is contained in a .iff file with a specific name.

It turns out that the .iff file is embedded in a plaintext portion of the encrypted file. I have clawed this out, and it hints at it being Blowfish.

The 4 byte header is "BLFS". The next int32 after that is 0x80. Then follows 16 bytes of random binary string (128 bits). Then, two more int32s... 0x75 and 0x01. Following that, 120 bytes of binary string (not 117?), and 4 nulls. The last bit I think is safe to assume as padding, as the parent file requires some weird byte-alignment scheme.

I have many examples of these encrypted files. The 128bit string changes, file to file. The 120byte string changes, file to file. BLFS, 0x80, 0x75, and 0x01 all remain constant.

I am a cryptography noob. The 120byte string is far too long to be a Blowfish key, which maxes out at 56 bytes. The 128bit string is a better bet (it has that nice round power-of-two number that the original implementor would have liked). I know that an algorithm like this would also require an iv, but aren't those short? In some cases, just a byte?

Is this iff file I've extracted the magic sauce, and is it the sort that I think it is? I'm not able to make sense of what I'm seeing, and I'm not sure what research I need to do next to accomplish that.

Apologies if this question isn't a fit for this SE, please comment and let me know that before closing.

Comment: My first guess, seeing the BLFS, is blowfish as well. However, as long as there are no obvious clues to the format within the file itself, it's a "everything is possible, nothing is certain" thing. Do you happen to have the application that reads or writes these files? Reversing that application is likely to be the only way to go any further.

Comment: I have access to two applications that read this. It was released for both Windows and Mac. The Windows version may actually have anti-debugger features, but I haven't tried. Not yet anyway.

Comment: First thin I'd do is run the program with procmon active, check how it reads the file (does it seek to where the BLFS string is and read a fixed number of bytes before rewinding the file and reading the rest?) and check the stack when these calls happen. This alone might give you some clues about how the file "works", which could help in determining which parts to reverse.

Comment: As far as I know blowfish has 64 bit block length (which is rare) and (also as far as I know) doesn't have IV. There is also no any guarantee that the key is contained in the file in usable form (or at all). So @Guntram Blohm is right, reverse engineering is inevitable here.

Comment: run `nm`/`strings` on the Mac program and see if you see any mention of blowfish (or other cipher). Many Mac developers are lazy/careless and don't strip their binaries.

Comment: I actually have the h includes from the Mac version. Some commercial library called FataMorgana, so all the function names are prefixed FM. Nothing in those about Blowfish, nothing in any of the binaries or shared objects hints at Blowfish. I can also guess the first byte of dozens/hundreds of most of the ciphertexts.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky  "nm" on one of the shared objects on the mac version turns up a bunch of function names with "Blowfish" in them. Thanks. Now if only I could decrypt the dumb things.

Comment: Since you have a program that can read the files, a useful test would be to try to modify the files (e.g. by flipping a single bit in either the 16-byte or the 120-byte string) and see what happens. If you're lucky, the resulting output is only partly garbled; the way it changes (e.g. just one bit in the decoded data flipped, a whole 8-byte block garbled, everything after the flipped bit garbled, etc.) should indicate what encryption mode is used. If you're less lucky, the decryption will simply fail, which suggests the presence of some kind of a checksum or a MAC, but even that's useful info.

Comment: Don't forget you surely have salt. 120 - 56 = 64, a nice number.

Comment: Function names in the library do indicate a salt, a block-chaining process to get around the 64bit block limitation, a "password", and initialization vectors. Likely some of the magic sauce is in the executable, the library, or both. The mac version has croaks on El Capitan, so I'm probably stuck trying to do something on the windows end of it. Focusing on proxying the dll for now. Thanks @ikegami and everyone else. Haven't given up yet, but this might be out of my league.